# Gnuplot: Convert integer to ASCII value

Tags: ascii, gnuplot, type-conversion, data-conversion

I would like to generate multiple plots within one gnuplot script, and would like to start each plot's title with a running capital letter, i.e., the first plot will have the title `(A) sample title for first chart`, the second one `(B) sample title for second chart`, and so on.

In Java, for this I basically have to do

```
int i = 65;       // ASCII value for 65
char c = (char)i; // Convert 65 to corresponding ASCII value ('A')
i++;
// Use c; then repeat
```

I just tried something similar in gnuplot by using [`gprintf`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node183.html) and using the `%c` formatter, yet I could not get it working due to the problem

> These format specifiers are not the same as those used by the standard C-language routine sprintf().

Long question short: How to convert an integer to its corresponding [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gnuplot> print sprintf("%c", 65)
#A
```

Gnuplot provides a [gprintf](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node183.html) which uses gnuplot format specifiers and sprintf.

Comment: Thanks, works as expected! Somehow overlooked sprintf and only found gprintf.